# iPhone UIStringDrawing usage

Tags: iphone, sdk, string, drawing

Could someone please explain to me how to draw a
string using UIStringDrawing instead of using a label? here is my code but for some reason it compiles and the screen is blank...

```
//
// MainViewController.m
// DotH
//

#define WINDOW_FRAME [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]
#define SCREEN_FRAME [UIScreen mainScreen].applicationFrame
#define GRAY [UIColor grayColor]
#define BLACK [UIColor blackColor]

@implementation MainViewController

- (void)loadView {

  UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:SCREEN_FRAME];
  [view setBackgroundColor:GRAY];

  [BLACK setFill];

  NSString *string = @"Hey Dude!";
  [string drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(50, 50) withFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14]];

  self.view = view;
  [view release];

}

@end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The line

```
[string drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(50, 50) withFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14]];
```

needs to be in the view's `drawRect:` method.

This is because just before `drawRect:` is called, the rectangle passed as an argument to `drawRect:` is erased.  So if you try to do custom drawing anywhere other than a view's `drawRect:` method, the stuff you draw will get erased whenever `drawRect:` is called.  (Not to mention that calling `drawAtPoint:` is meaningless if not done by code within a UIView.)

You will need to make a custom subclass of `UIView`, and that subclass will need a custom `drawRect:` method.  If you still want the view controller to be the entity responsible for deciding what string should be drawn and how, you should give your UIView subclass a method like

```
- (void)addString:(NSString *)string atPoint:(CGPoint)point withFont:(UIFont *)font;
```

That method can store that information, in, e.g., three `NSMutableArray`s (one of strings, one of points, and one of fonts), and increment a counter of how many strings have been added.  Then, your view's `drawRect:` method can draw the strings described in those arrays.  To add a string, your view controller just calls `addString:atPoint:withFont:` on your view.